# source control plugin for PowerShell Plus

Tags: powershell, version-control

Propably this is not the right place to ask for this, but here it goes:

I have installed Powershell Plus and I would like to integrate TFS source control to it.

Does anyone know which plugin should I install or what should I do to get it integrated with the TFS source control?